# Why do I need 'call' in the return statement 'Function.call.apply( this, arguments )'

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hi guys,

So I was browsing through [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/), and I came across a snippet of code that I didn't fully understand. 
In `Person.fullname`, I noticed that it has the following snippet of code (I have attached the snippet at the bottom of my post).

`return Function.call.apply( Person.prototype.fullname, arguments );`

#### What is the difference between the code above and the following code?

`return Function.apply( Person.prototype.fullname, arguments );`

#### Edit

---

I noticed that when I changed the code above to the following, it started working.

`return Person.fullname.call.apply( Person.prototype.fullname, arguments );`

---

My new question would be: Is

`return Person.fullname.call.apply( Person.prototype.fullname, arguments )`

**the same as**

```
return Function.call.apply( Person.prototype.fullname, arguments ); ?
```

Right now, if I remove `call` from either of the methods, I get an error and I don't understand why we need that `call` before `apply`.

#### ~~` End of Edit

As of now, I am currently uncertain about how this piece of code behaves. Detailed explanation of how it works and when it should be applied would help tremendously. Thank you!

```
function Person(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}
Person.prototype.fullname = function(joiner, options) {
  options = options || { order: "western" };
  var first = options.order === "western" ? this.first : this.last;
  var last =  options.order === "western" ? this.last  : this.first;
  return first + (joiner || " ") + last;
};

// Create an unbound version of "fullname", usable on any object with 'first'
// and 'last' properties passed as the first argument. This wrapper will
// not need to change if fullname changes in number or order of arguments.
Person.fullname = function() {
  // Result: Person.prototype.fullname.call(this, joiner, ..., argN);
  return Function.call.apply(Person.prototype.fullname, arguments);
};

var grace = new Person("Grace", "Hopper");

// 'Grace Hopper'
grace.fullname();

// 'Turing, Alan'
Person.fullname({ first: "Alan", last: "Turing" }, ", ", { order: "eastern" });
```

Comment: Does the second one work at all? One would expect that calling `Function.apply` directly like that would have issues. The first one actually uses `apply` to call the native `call` function with a "this" value and an array-like arguments list.

Comment: I don't see the second syntax anywhere in that example, did you just make it up? 0.o about the first syntax: see @adeneo's comment

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my answer. In the meanwhile, I will try to wrap my head around what you just said.

Comment: @nonchip I just updated my question to make it more applicable/revelant to my query. I will re-update my answer to avoid confusion. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: now that code confuses me even more… afraid i'll be not much of a help there… back in my days, JS objects were just fancy functions and you didn't really touch prototypes often :P

Comment: You can call certain functions with `apply` and set the `this` value and arguments. For instance `Array.prototype.slice.apply` calls the `slice` method with `apply()`. You're calling the built in `call()` method *with* `apply`, and this is done so you can pass a `this` value and an array of arguments etc. Just calling `Function,apply` isn't even the same function, as again, the function you're using is `call`, it's just called with `apply`, which is somewhat confusing, but a neat trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response guys. I updated the title of my question to make it hopefully more clearer to you guys the part that I dont understand. In the meanwhile, I will read through the responses posted.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't think it gets more "duplicated" than that !

Comment: @Barmar. Wow, thank you. How come I didnt come across that before? 
adeneo: Thank you so much for going out of your way to try and explain the concept to me. I am still trying to wrap my head around it haha.
nonchip. No problem. Thank you for trying. Javascript has indeed evolved a lot over the years.

Comment: I'm not sure because that question is about `Function.call.apply` versus `Function.apply`, but this seems to be about `<class>.<method>.call.apply` versus `Function.call.apply(<class>.prototype.<method>`

Comment: When you do a combination of call and apply like so: `call.apply(o,a)` what this means is that first apply runs, and after it runs, you're essentially running `o.call(a[0],a.slice(1))` but just in a safer fashion.

Comment: @J.Lee Not sure how you missed it. I just put `[javascript] function.call.apply` in the SO search box and it was the first match.

Comment: @Barmar: yeah, I am quite surprised at myself as well (quite negligent of me).  Instead of searching in stack overflow directly, I did a google search. Need to get adjusted in using stack overflow's search engine. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ultimater, so that means, the first item in the array will essentially be set to 'this' and the function ('o' in your example) would be called? I think its starting to make more sense to me now (hopefully I got it right :p haha).

Comment: @J.Lee Right. Hence the slice usage.